# python excel check if domain name is in url column

Tags: python, excel

I am having a project that I wish to check if the domain that existed in the URL1 to URL3

[image]

If the domain do existing in URL1 to URL3 as picture below, the `Check` should be `TRUE`, and if the domain don't existing in any columns in URL1 to URL3 (for example yah.com in URL3) the the `Check` should be `FAlSE`
I am still new to Python. Is there anyway no make it done ?

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as text.Show what have you tried ([mre]) and specific question about problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I assume it will be convenient to use the openpyxl python library. I'm assuming the domain is in column A, urls 1 to 3 are columns B, C, D, and the boolean should be set to I.

Code is something like:

```
pip install openpyxl

file = 'path/to/file/filename.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
i = 1
vd = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
while vd.strip():
    vu1 = sheet[f'B{i}'].value
    vu2 = sheet[f'C{i}'].value
    vu3 = sheet[f'D{i}'].value
    
    if vd in vu1 and vd in vu1 and vd in vu1:
        sheet[f'I{i}'] = '=TRUE()'
    else:
        sheet[f'I{i}'] = '=FALSE()'
    
    i += 1
    vd = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
```

Also, you can use another from pandas, xlrd, xlutils or pyexcel libreries for solve this case.